# ERROR: Get-AzApiManagementProduct : The pipeline has been stopped. when adding api management user in Azure PS Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

I have been trying to automate the following script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/scripts/powershell-add-user-and-get-subscription-key?toc=/powershell/module/toc.json

via Azure Functions.

```sh
    # generate a subscription key for the user to call apis which are part of the 'Starter' product
    $body = New-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $context -UserId $user.UserId `
        -ProductId $product.ProductId -Name $subscriptionName -State $subscriptionState
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body
})
```

My code is actually trying to return that subscription key and a `200`, which I'm definitely not getting back. I have a feeling it has something to do with the following weird logging, which I'll include in full below:

```
[6/12/2020 7:01:18 AM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000FFE6585A'.
[6/12/2020 7:01:21 AM] Executing HTTP request: {
[6/12/2020 7:01:21 AM]   "requestId": "da9db8fe-4f3e-4d31-a69b-447a352d587b",
[6/12/2020 7:01:21 AM]   "method": "POST",
[6/12/2020 7:01:21 AM]   "uri": "/api/course_api_mgmt"
[6/12/2020 7:01:21 AM] }
[6/12/2020 7:01:21 AM] Executing 'Functions.course_api_mgmt' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=bfc24fc2-1ecc-440d-84d2-52ef29248c9e)
[6/12/2020 7:01:32 AM] System Log: { Log-Level: Trace; Log-Message: Profile invocation completed in 11164 ms. }
[6/12/2020 7:01:32 AM] System Log: { Invocation-Id: bfc24fc2-1ecc-440d-84d2-52ef29248c9e; Log-Level: Trace; Log-Message: Invoking function 'course_api_mgmt' code 11295 ms after receiving request. Invocation performance details: DependenciesAvailable: 0 ms; RunspaceAvailable: 11187 ms; MetadataAndTraceContextReady: 11287 ms; FunctionCodeReady: 11290 ms; InputBindingValuesReady: 11294 ms; InvokingFunctionCode: 11294 ms;  }
[6/12/2020 7:01:32 AM] INFORMATION: PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[6/12/2020 7:01:34 AM] WARNING: The provided service principal secret will be included in the 'AzureRmContext.json' file found in the user profile ( C:\Users\******\.Azure ). Please ensure that this directory has appropriate
protections.
[6/12/2020 7:01:34 AM] OUTPUT: 
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: Account                              SubscriptionName TenantId                             Environment
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: -------                              ---------------- --------                             -----------
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: ****** course_api_mgmt  ****** AzureCloud
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: 
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: Name               : course_api_mgmt (******) - ******
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: Account            : ******
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: Environment        : AzureCloud
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: Subscription       : ******
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: Tenant             : ******
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: TokenCache         : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Core.ProtectedFileTokenCache
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: VersionProfile     : 
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: ExtendedProperties : {}
[6/12/2020 7:01:36 AM] OUTPUT: 
[6/12/2020 7:01:37 AM] INFORMATION: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Models.PsApiManagementContext
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] INFORMATION: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Models.PsApiManagementUser
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] ERROR: Get-AzApiManagementProduct : The pipeline has been stopped.
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] At C:\Users\******\AzureProjects\course_api_mgmt\course_api_mgmt\run.ps1:56 char:16
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] + ...  $product = Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $context -Title 'Star ...
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzApiManagementProduct], PipelineStoppedException
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementProduct
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM]  
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] Script stack trace:
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM]    at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\******\AzureProjects\course_api_mgmt\course_api_mgmt\run.ps1: line 56
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM]
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM] System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Pipe.AddItems(Object objects)
[6/12/2020 7:01:39 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime._WriteObjectsSkipAllowCheck(Object sendToPipeline)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementProduct.ExecuteApiManagementCmdlet()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.AzureApiManagementCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] Result: ERROR: Get-AzApiManagementProduct : The pipeline has been stopped.
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] At C:\Users\******\AzureProjects\course_api_mgmt\course_api_mgmt\run.ps1:56 char:16
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] + ...  $product = Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $context -Title 'Star ...
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzApiManagementProduct], PipelineStoppedException
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementProduct
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]  
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] Script stack trace:
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\******\AzureProjects\course_api_mgmt\course_api_mgmt\run.ps1: line 56
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Pipe.AddItems(Object objects)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime._WriteObjectsSkipAllowCheck(Object sendToPipeline)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementProduct.ExecuteApiManagementCmdlet()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.AzureApiManagementCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]
Exception: The pipeline has been stopped.
Stack:    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Pipe.AddItems(Object objects)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime._WriteObjectsSkipAllowCheck(Object sendToPipeline)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementProduct.ExecuteApiManagementCmdlet()
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.AzureApiManagementCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet().
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: 
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: ProductId            : starter
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: Title                : Starter
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: Description          : Subscribers will be able to run 5 calls/minute up to a maximum of 100 calls/week.
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: LegalTerms           : 
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: SubscriptionRequired : True
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: ApprovalRequired     : False
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: SubscriptionsLimit   : 1
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: State                : Published
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: Id                   : /subscriptions/******/resourceGroups/******/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/******/products/starter
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: ResourceGroupName    : ******
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: ServiceName          : ******
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] OUTPUT: 
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] Executed 'Functions.course_api_mgmt' (Succeeded, Id=bfc24fc2-1ecc-440d-84d2-52ef29248c9e)
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] Executed HTTP request: {
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]   "requestId": "da9db8fe-4f3e-4d31-a69b-447a352d587b",
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]   "method": "POST",
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]   "uri": "/api/course_api_mgmt",
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]   "identities": [
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]     {
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]       "level": "Admin"
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]     }
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]   ],
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]   "status": 204,
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM]   "duration": 19341
[6/12/2020 7:01:40 AM] }
```

The function is clearly working in that it does the physical job of creating the user

[image]

but this is of little use if I am unable to return the subscription key in the response body.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Edit: followed a suggestion to iteratively run commands in my local Powershell ISE terminal

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Module -Name AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit

PS C:\Windows\system32> $userEmail = "test3@gmail.com"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $userFirstName = "Test"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $userLastName = "User"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "234" -AsPlainText -Force

PS C:\Windows\system32> $userNote = ""

PS C:\Windows\system32> $subscriptionId = "**********************"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $apimServiceName = "**********************"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $resourceGroupName = "**********************"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $userState = "Active"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $subscriptionName = "**********************"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $subscriptionState = "Active"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $User = "**********************"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String **********************" -AsPlainText -Force

PS C:\Windows\system32> $tenant = "**********************"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User,$PWord

PS C:\Windows\system32> if ($PSVersionTable.PSEdition -eq 'Desktop' -and (Get-Module -Name AzureRM -ListAvailable)) {
    Write-Warning -Message ('Az module not installed. Having both the AzureRM and ' +
      'Az modules installed at the same time is not supported.')
} else {
    Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
}

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy
Restricted

PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-Module Az.Accounts

PS C:\Windows\system32> Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -ServicePrincipal
WARNING: The provided service principal secret will be included in the 'AzureRmContext.json' file found in the user profile ( C:\Users\Aubrey\.Azure ). Please ensure that
 this directory has appropriate protections.

Account                              SubscriptionName TenantId                             Environment
-------                              ---------------- --------                             -----------
********************** **********************  ********************** AzureCloud 



PS C:\Windows\system32> Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

Name                                     Account                          SubscriptionName                Environment                     TenantId                       
----                                     -------                          ----------------                -----------                     --------                       
********************** (**********************... **********************... **********************                 AzureCloud                      **********************...



PS C:\Windows\system32> $context = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServiceName $apimServiceName

PS C:\Windows\system32> $context

ResourceGroupName ServiceName
----------------- -----------
**********************       ********************** 



PS C:\Windows\system32> $user = New-AzApiManagementUser -Context $context -FirstName $userFirstName -LastName $userLastName `
        -Password $userPassword -State $userState -Note $userNote -Email $userEmail

PS C:\Windows\system32> $user


UserId            : d3938bdc824e4674a1c0b0d159f56638
FirstName         : Test
LastName          : User
Email             : test3@gmail.com
State             : Active
RegistrationDate  : 6/12/2020 9:01:09 PM
Note              : 
Identities        : {[test3@gmail.com, Basic]}
Id                : /subscriptions/**********************/resourceGroups/**********************/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/**********************/users/**********************
ResourceGroupName : **********************
ServiceName       : **********************


PS C:\Windows\system32> $product = Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $context -Title 'Starter' | Select-Object -First 1
Get-AzApiManagementProduct : The pipeline has been stopped.
At line:1 char:12
+ $product = Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $context -Title 'Start ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzApiManagementProduct], PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementProduct



ProductId            : starter
Title                : Starter
Description          : Subscribers will be able to run 5 calls/minute up to a maximum of 100 calls/week.
LegalTerms           : 
SubscriptionRequired : True
ApprovalRequired     : False
SubscriptionsLimit   : 1
State                : Published
Id                   : /subscriptions/**********************/resourceGroups/**********************/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/**********************/products/start
                       er
ResourceGroupName    : **********************
ServiceName          : **********************


PS C:\Windows\system32> $body = New-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $context -UserId $user.UserId `
        -ProductId $product.ProductId -Name $subscriptionName -State $subscriptionState
New-AzApiManagementSubscription : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ProductId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and 
then try the command again.
At line:2 char:20
+         -ProductId $product.ProductId -Name $subscriptionName -State  ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-AzApiManagementSubscription], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.NewAzureApiManagementSubscription


PS C:\Windows\system32> $product

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this code (without the Functions-specific stuff) in a regular PowerShell Core 6 session? So far, it looks like the Get-AzApiManagementProduct cmdlet fails for its own reasons, potentially unrelated to Functions. If you can reproduce this outside of Functions, it will be easier to diagnose. If this happens in Functions only, please feel free to file an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues.

Comment: @AnatoliBeliaev that helped a little bit, ill update the question with the output but creating the product is still triggering the same exception and giving my `$product` variable a null value which is breaking the subscription key step

Comment: so i think its reproduced outside of functions

Comment: If you can reproduce this outside of Functions, I suggest reporting this to the Azure PS module owners: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues

Comment: @AnatoliBeliaev It seems that we cannot run `Get-AzApiManagementProduct` and `Select-Object -Frist 1` in the pipeline. Please try to update command as `$product = Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $context -Title 'Starter'   

$product = $product | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: that worked! @JimXu feel free to leave that as an answer and I will credit you

Comment: @AnatoliBeliaev I have posted my suggestions as an answer. Since it is helpful for you, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I summarize the solution as below.

According to the error message, we cannot run the command `Get-AzApiManagementProduct` and `Select-Object -Frist 1` in the PowerShell pipeline. So I suggest you update the command `Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $context -Title 'Starter' | Select-Object -First 1` to

```
$product = Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $context -Title 'Starter'     
$product = $product | Select-Object -First 1
```